# Logo in the address bar

Tags: css

How do i do if I want the logo to appear in the address bar?
  I tried to add link to a jpg I saved as favicon but doesn't work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="general-style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sequence-style.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
```

Comment: We usually put favicon.ico in the site root folder. if you specify an .ico file why did you add 'a link to jpg' ?

Comment: Most browsers don't add the favicon to the *address bar* anymore.  This is for security purposes.  People were using lock icons as favicons to trick others into thinking their site was secured.

Comment: What does "jpg I saved as favicon" mean?  Are you sure it's *actually* an `.ico` file?  Is the path correct?  Maybe try an absolute path? `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://yoursite.com/images/favicon.ico">`

Comment: @RocketHazmat This saddens me, as I hate the non-unique images next to the URL now :-(

Comment: @TylerH: That's I hate people!  Someone's always gotta go and ruin it for everyone!

Comment: My bad...I saved the logo as favicon I meant. Thx y'all for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually put both of these

```
<link rel='icon' href='favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon' />
<link rel='shortcut icon' href='favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon' />
```

In some browsers if the icon file is in the root they actually seek them out even if you dont put the links in.

Answer (score 0):

A favicon should be in ICO format, not JPEG, if you want it to show up in most browsers. That is the only format that Internet Explorer supports before version 11.

Some other formats are supported, if you accept that it won't work at all in some browsers. See the [File format support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#File_format_support) chart.

If you search the web for "favicon" you will find several online converters where you can convert your image to ICO format.